# Passive equivalent of "How did you get this book?"

Tags: passive-voice

What would be the passive version of "How did you get this book?" Could you also explain why? It has to be changed into passive voice, it is currently in active voice. Also, please elaborate on what is correct according to grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sentence, *get* means *obtain, come by, find,...*. But you can't say that the book *was got*, that would be incorrect.

Some example sentences:

Passive, with *you* as the subject:

> - By whom **were** you **given** this book?
> - You **were given** this book by whom?
> - **Were** you **given** this book?

Passive, with *book* as the subject:

> - How/Where **was** this book **found/obtained/bought/sold**?
> - This book **was found/obtained/bought/sold**?
> - **Was** this book **given** to you?

Comment: Can it be "how was this book given to you?"

Comment: Yes, that's a correct sentence as well.

Comment: @user20078 Note:  _"How was this book given to you"_ is a correct sentence.  It sounds like it means _"What was the actual action that resulted in your having this book?"_  An answer might be "The author invited me on stage, shook my right hand and handed me the book with his left."  Or maybe _"The book was delivered to me by drone while I sat by the pool."_  The answer would not be _"The author thought I deserved it"_  or _"My name was pulled from a bucket of ping pong balls."_  These backstories would be more appropriate as responses to your original question (_"How did you get this book?"_)